# Maintain a draft copy of form data in local state from props set via connect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have written a simple React Component in Typescript which accepts Redux state data via connect into the components props to allow a user to edit their profile info.  The profile state in Redux state is much larger and includes fields that are not editable by a user.

I don't want to bind the input fields directly to redux state as I want them to "Save" before the state is updated, therefore I need some sort of local state.  The fields also need to have state in order for real-time validation, etc.

I can't seem to figure out a way of feeding the current state values into the fields and then allowing the user to change them without updating the redux state until the user hits "Save".

My code below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from './../../store';
import * as ProfileState from './../../store/Profile';

// At runtime, Redux will merge together...
type ProfileEditorProps =
    EditableProfileProps        // ... state we've requested from the Redux store
    & typeof ProfileState.actionCreators      // ... plus action creators we've requested

/** Subset of state fields mapped onto props via connect */
interface EditableProfileProps {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
}

// Defines state that matches the props def
interface ModifiedProfileState extends EditableProfileProps { }

class UserProfileEditor extends React.Component<ProfileEditorProps, ModifiedProfileState> {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.handleFieldContentChange = this.handleFieldContentChange.bind(this);
        this.state = { firstName: '', lastName: ''} as ModifiedProfileState;
    }

    // updates the user's profile
    saveChanges() {
        // fire action to update redux state with new values
    }

    handleFieldContentChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        this.setState( {...this.state, [e.target.name] : e.target.value});
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                </div>
                <div className="form-horizontal col-md-9">
                    <div className="form-group"><label className="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-7"><input type="text" name="firstName" onChange={ this.handleFieldContentChange } value={this.state.firstName} className="form-control" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group"><label className="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-7"><input type="text" name="lastName" onChange={ this.handleFieldContentChange } value={this.state.lastName} className="form-control" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <button className="btn btn-default" type="submit">Cancel</button>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">Save Changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.profile as EditableProfileProps, // Use editable props def when pulling from state
    ProfileState.actionCreators                                         // Get action creators
)(UserProfileEditor) as any;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's perfectly fine to set your initial state in your constructor using `props` if you're only using it as 'seed data' for your inputs. By setting it in your constructor, it's only setting it as the initial state and not binding it. The state in the component will still be controlled but independent of Redux so you're free to modify it and then dispatch it as a payload when your user clicks 'Save'.

`this.state = { firstName: props.firstName, lastName: props.lastName} as ModifiedProfileState;`

Comment: I've tried that approach, but I find sometimes that the state hasn't been mapped to props when the constructor fires?  It seems to happen more when I refresh the whole page.  If i simple change from component to component that approach appears to work.

Comment: You could use `static getDerivedStateFromProps` to wait for your props to be mapped and then setState. If your reducer has a loading state internalized, it's easy to check if loading has completed and then have logic to only return the new props to state if the state hasn't already been set.

Comment: I would set my initial input states to `false` or something that's very distinct from user input. In `static getDerivedStateFromProps`, I would check to see if: a) my inputs are still false and b) if the correct props have arrived from the store. If all is good,`return { firstName: props.firstName ... }` otherwise `return null`.

Comment: I can't seem to get `getDerivedStateFromProps` to fire?

Comment: Did you declare it as a static method? `static getDerivedStateFromProps() { }`

Comment: Yes I have.  I ended up getting it working by checking a loaded property on the redux store object and copying props into state in the constructor if true where not previously true locally.  I'm wondering if I've got a version mismatch with my react-doc package.  I'm using 16.4.1 of both react and react-dom.